# Python: Need to wait before BeautifulSoup and Urllib can parse a website

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to get the current world population in real-time but when the webpage first loads up it takes a couple seconds to retrieve the data. When i run the program i get loading... instead of the population number. Is there a way to wait until the webpage fully loads before retrieving the info? 
Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import *

htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.theworldcounts.com/counters/shocking_environmental_facts_and_statistics/world_population_clock_live")

htmltext = htmlfile.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
body = soup.find(text="World population").find_previous('p')

print (body.text)
```

Comment: well, you could add time.sleep(30), to wait for 30 seconds, or while loop until the value it's not `loading...`

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

html = requests.get("http://www.theworldcounts.com/counters/shocking_environmental_facts_and_statistics/world_population_clock_live").text

while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    body = soup.find(text="World population").find_previous('p')
    if str(body.text).find('loading...') > 1:
        print (body.text)
        break
    time.sleep(30)
    html = requests.get("http://www.theworldcounts.com/counters/shocking_environmental_facts_and_statistics/world_population_clock_live").text
```

Comment: Have you trued running this program before? It didn't seem to work for me :(

Comment: I haven't actually, guess you need a javascript parser.

Comment: You do not think it is possible to do this with python?

Comment: Yes it's possible, it's just the module you need it's not BeautifulSop, you need some Javascript scraper maybe this: https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape

Comment: I found another website that loads the data from the start and changes as i reload the page, so that fixes my problem. Thanks for the help anyways :)

Comment: OP, why didn't you share the link you found?

Answer (score 0):

You need engine which can interpret javascript from web page you are downloading.

Better solution is to find some static version of the site or another site with such information (and I am sure that this site do not actually give any information - only extrapolate data)

But if you REALLY want to use dryscape you may use such approach

```
   # visiting desired site
   session.set_html("<html></html>")
   session.visit(link)
   # wait 
   session.driver.wait_for(lambda: watToWait(session))
```

And function that says that page is already downloaded is:

```
   def watToWait(session):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(session.body(), BEAUTIFUL_SOUP_PARSER)
        column = soup.find('td')
        if column is not None:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```